# How to style drop downs of drop down select boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

How to style drop downs of drop down select boxes?

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CGDhB/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="salmatWrapper">
        <div class="col-sm-12 contents">
            <img src="http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/alinta/images/header.png" alt="Energy Unit Conversion Tool" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="form">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 left">
                            <!-- Enter Value-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <input id="custom1" name="custom1" type="text" placeholder="Enter Value" class="form-control input-md">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Convert From -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <select id="custom2" name="custom2" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="" class="selectDefaultText">Convert From</option>
                                        <option value="1">Option one</option>
                                        <option value="2">Option two</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Convert To -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <select id="custom3" name="custom3" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="" class="selectDefaultText">Convert To</option>
                                        <option value="1">Option one</option>
                                        <option value="2">Option two</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 right">
                            <!-- Textarea -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="custom4" name="custom4">Result here ...</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <img src="http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/alinta/images/footer.png" alt="Check our affordable electrity and gas packages!" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the drop downs to look as in below image

[image]

Basically I want that little icon and the drop down select boxes to look as that. I am confused with this. A staging link may be viewed from here http://bit.ly/1eNm3jv

Comment: You're going to have to use something like jQuery with Uniform.js or some other form-styling plugin. You can't style actual `<select>` elements in such a way, the insides come under shadowDOM and most browsers won't let you change it much. Uniform.js works by replacing the form elements so they are styleable, and on change will update the original `<select>` element.

Comment: is there any particular jquery plugins you guys can direct me too? Uniform.js looks ok. Is there any others that you guys recommend?

Comment: I only really use Uniform.js. I've had to work with [Dropkick](http://robdel12.github.io/DropKick/) and hated it so, so much. I'm not really terribly knowledgeable about other plugins, just used those two, and prefer Uniform.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't style select. The only thing you can really do is border color and padding as far as I know. Probably font size as well. Like @setek mentioned, gonna have to use some kind of plugin.